# Ubuntu 17.10 doesn't shutdown properly: eth0: failed to remove key

Tags: 17.10, shutdown

Since a few days, Ubuntu 17.10 doesn't shutdown properly because when shutting down these messages appear:

```
eth0: failed to remove key(1, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-22)
```

Sometimes, after about 1 minute Ubuntu eventually shuts down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Try this:**

`gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

then change the following line from:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

To:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

And then, update the grub and reboot using :

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

2. **Otherwise:**

Upgrade the kernel to a newer version, since it is a bug; more details [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1720930)